# Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) error on Laravel 10, with file uploading form

Tags: laravel-sail, laravel-10

I'm getting back to Laravel, using SAIL and Laravel 10.
This is my blade form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('deposit') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <label class="form-label" for="amount">Amount:</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="amount" required autofocus>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="form-label" for="check">Check image:</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="file" name="check" id="check" required>
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <label class="form-label"></label>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Deposit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here are my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Deposit;

class DepositController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function showDepositForm()
    {
        return view('deposit.add');
    }

    public function createDeposit(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->file('check')->extension());
    }

    public function showPendingDeposits()
    {
    }
}
```

Finally, this is my route to this method:

```
Route::post('/deposit', 'App\Http\Controllers\DepositController@createDeposit')->name('deposit');
```

And I'm getting a server error. Nothing logged by Laravel, but at SAIL console I can read:

`WARN  172.20.0.1:56954 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF).`

If I remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute from the form tag, the EOF error disappears.

But if I do that, I can't upload the file. Any advices on what could be going on here?